# How to plot a list of IP addresses as active or inactive and save to a text file

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.7

```
import subprocess
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Main ():
    ipaddress = open('ipaddress.txt', 'a')
    with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
        for n in range(1, 100):
            ip="192.168.1.{0}".format(n)
            result=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip],
                stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
            if result:
                print (ip + " inactive")
                ipaddress.write(ip + ' inactive')
            else:
                print (ip + " active")
                ipaddress.write(ip + ' Acive')
    ip = ip.split('\n')
    ip = [float(f) for f in ip]
    slice_labels = ['Active', 'Inactive']
    # Create a pie chart from the values.
    plt.pie(ip, labels=slice_labels)
    # Add a title.
    plt.title('IP address activity')
    # Display the pie chart.
    plt.show()
Main()
```

The code prints to terminal and writes to a text file, but it is not plotting a pie chart. Also I am trying to figure out how I would allow the user an option to save to a text file as a yes or no rather than just force writing as it is set up currently, would I add another nested if else statement?

Comment: I guess you are missing one indentation level starting at ```ip = ip.split('\n')```.

Comment: Upon making that change I am getting a ValueError: could not convert string to float: '192.168.1.99'

Comment: Alright. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
import subprocess
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

addresses = Path('ipaddress.txt')
counter = Counter(a=0, i=0)

with addresses.open('w') as f:
    for n in range(1, 100):
        ip = f'192.168.1.{n}'

        cmd = subprocess.run(
            ['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '200', ip],
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
        )

        if cmd.returncode:
            print(f'{ip} inactive')
            f.write(f'{ip} inactive\n')
            counter.update('i')
        else:
            print(f'{ip} active')
            f.write(f'{ip} active\n')
            counter.update('a')

labels = ['Active', 'Inactive']
plt.pie(counter.values(), labels=labels)
plt.title('IP address activity')
plt.show()
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You. This is helpful, however when I run this all the addresses are coming back as inactive.

Comment: What operating system are you using? On Linux my command is ```['/bin/ping', '-n', '-q', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', ip]``` and that is working fine for me.

Comment: Windows. I got it figured out. On this line:  ip = f'192.168.0.{n}' Just had to change to  ip = f'192.168.1.{n}' to get the correct output Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh! I see. That was my local network, where I was testing. Sorry for that. If possible, mark my answer as accepted. :-)

Comment: No problem, I accepted it, thanks for the help! take care cya around :)